# iOS develop about NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I know the two ways to get a operation queue as follow:

```
queue1 = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
queue2 = [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] retain];
```

But I don't know what differences between them.

```
[queue1 addOperation:operation1]; 
[queue2 addOperation:operation2];
```

which thread does operation1 run on?main thread? or uncertainty?

I tested.

```
operation1 --> sometimes mainthread sometimes not. 
operation2 --> always mainthread.
```

Answer (score 1):

[According to the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004592) NSOperationQueue's:

> create separate threads for non-concurrent operations and launch
>   concurrent operations from the current thread.

This explains why some of your task operate on the main thread and others don't.

The `mainQueue` is bound to the main thread, so operations are always performed on the main thread.

Comment: The documentation about `NSOperationQueue` is a bit outdated. The docs for `NSOperation` note that as of Mac OS X 10.6 (and presumably iOS 4.0) _all_ operations are started from a separate thread and the value returned from `isConcurrent` is ignored.

Comment: The docs also cover this: in OS X, but _not_ iOS, NSOperationQueues are implemented using GCD: "As a result, operations are always executed on a separate thread." My quote above is in an iOS-specific section. (This may be different in iOS5. I've not checked and couldn't quote from it yet anyway.)

Comment: Actually... I see what you mean. There are technotes (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#qa/qa1712/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010262) that suggest that iOS4 _does_ use GCD.

Comment: You beat me to it, I was just looking for that link.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, Stephen is correct.

The main purpose is to Create separate threads for non-concurrent operations and launch concurrent operations from the current thread.

In this case

```
queue1 = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
```

the queue1 is the queue which belongs to the thread from which you have invoked i.e., if the above line is invoked from a detached thread then it would not belong to main thread.

but with

```
queue2 = [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] retain];
```

You are externally getting the queue from the ios in other words 1st is local to the VC/Class called and second one is global (one for one application in ios 4)